# Images not showing on GITHUB

Tags: html, image, github, github-pages

I created a new project, all images are loading locally, 'title.png' isn't on github hosted page.
you can find the repo: https://github.com/vedant-shah/treasure-hunt-app

and the hosted file: https://vedant-shah.github.io/treasure-hunt-app/

The folders are as:

- **g1(folder)**

  - q1.html
- **title.png**

while trying to open **title.png** from **q1.html**, I used '**/title.png**' as you can see in the code snippet below

```html
<img src="/title.png" alt="" width="300">
```

anyone know what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reference is wrong.
You can try with this code:

```
src="../title.png"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, could you explain the significance of ".." and "/"in github?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).